# MVC Unit test case

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following line in my controller method:

```
string str = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Session["String"].ToString();
```

In MVC for running unit test cases I have to mock the Session value, can any body please let me know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP/NET MVC: Test Controllers w/Sessions? Mocking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176347/asp-net-mvc-test-controllers-w-sessions-mocking)

Comment: try to search for a similar question before posting

Comment: if the controller has String str= HttpContext.Session["String"].ToString(); then it will work. if controller has String Str = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Session["String"].ToString(); it will not work because mock generally expects virtual method, as HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Session doen't contain the virtual method.

Answer (score 0):

[This will help you](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/07/01/asp-net-mvc-tip-12-faking-the-controller-context.aspx) - this will help you